# How to get files uploaded on another location in wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 1 asp.net mvc project which has folder like below:

```
D:\MymvcProject\MyApp\FileUpload\MyFiles\Csv\20161228122740\abc.txt

Folder = MymvcProject
MyApp =  Name of Mvc project
FileUpload = Folder inside mvc project
MyFiles = Folder inside FileUpload Folder
20161228122740 = Timestamp Folder inside csv folder which contains csv files
```

Now i want to read this csv files from my wcf project like below :

```
string path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/FileUpload/MyFiles/Csv/"), "20161228122740", "Abc.txt")
```

This is trying to find in my wcf project but my csv resides in mvc project folder so i am getting error `Could not find a part of the path`.

Now i can hard code path but problem will be when my publish website and put it to another drive like **for eg:F** drive then how my wcf service will gonna find that csv files and now drive have been changes.

Can anybody please guide me how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

you can add a key value in your web config like this:

```
<add key="FilePath" value="D:\MymvcProject\MyApp\FileUpload\MyFiles\Csv\"/>
```

then use it like this in your code:

```
string path = Path.Combine(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"], "20161228122740", "Abc.txt")
```

personally i prefer to sore this in my database.